# Write char to struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Basically I have a struct which stores my general program settings. I read in a config with the callback function to get the corresponding value, but I can't write it to the struct. I've tried everything from memcpy over strcpy to dereferencing the char pointer, but every time the char in the struct stays empty. The passed string contains only one char, I checked that multiple times. Also if I strcpy a string to the other fields of the struct, it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct {
    char *datafile;
    char *logfile;
    char mode;
} general_settings;

void setSettingsData(void){
    log_trace("parsing config file for general settings initialisation");
    config_error_t rc = config_parse("config.ini", handle_settings_ini_file);
    if (rc != CONFIG_ERROR_NONE) {
        log_error("Error parsing configuration: %s on line %lu", config_get_error_string(rc), config_get_line_number());
    } else {
        log_info("Settings parsed successfully!");
    }
}

static config_error_t handle_settings_ini_file(char *section, char *key, char *value) {
    if(section != NULL && !strcmp("Allgemein", section)) {
        if (!strcmp("mode", key)) {
            general_settings.mode = strdup(value); // ??????
            log_info("Program Execution mode set to %s", value);
        } else {
            log_fatal("Unrecognized setting. Check for typos. Exiting...");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return CONFIG_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `value` is a `char *`, you can get the `char` it points to with `*value`.

So you want `general_settings.mode = *value;`.

You could also use `general_settings.mode = value[0];`

Since `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)`, `*(value + 0)` is the same as `value[0]` and also the same as `*value`.

Comment: @Chris Can you be more precise about what you mean by "it doesn't work"? What code did you try? How did you test it? What results did you expect? What results did you obtain?

Comment: The result is always that the char field in `general_settings` is empty. I am expecting to write the char from `*value` to `general_settings.mode`. I've tried strcpy, strdup, memcpy, dereferencing the pointer and accessing it with `value[0]`.

Comment: @Chris How did you determine that it was empty? What value of `char` is empty? (Empty is not a character, as far as I know.)

Comment: When I tried to read it, it caused a segmentation fault, i.e. not empty meaning there are no characters in it but empty meaning the memory for this variable does not exist.

Comment: strdup returns a pointer to the newly allocated string, you are not dereferencing that general_settings.mode = strdup(value); now I did rewrite your snippet completely and got it working, but I really dont want to paste it as answer since it is not an answer :) https://pastebin.com/5jAEp9wJ

Comment: Thank you for your work, will try to get it to work :)

Comment: @Chris if you don't get it working in a few days, paste the whole thing and lets have a look.

Comment: I found my problem. Neither did I use typedef nor did I give the struct a name. That apparently was the reason that the members of `general_settings` were non-accessible with `=` and I couldn't give `mode` any value. Though I don't know exactly why that is a problem. @Sorenp thank you very much

Comment: You don't need to use typedef persay, but you most certainly need a variable of struct type to access anything (or a pointer).